# How to install gitslave on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, git, make

I'm trying to install gitslave (as part of a CircleCI [build](https://travis-ci.org/vladbailescu/sightly-slaves/jobs/645307678)) on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and it fails at `make`:

```
+tar -xzvf gitslave-2.0.2.tar.gz
gitslave-2.0.2/
gitslave-2.0.2/web/
gitslave-2.0.2/web/index.html
gitslave-2.0.2/web/Makefile
gitslave-2.0.2/web/ReleaseNotes.txt
gitslave-2.0.2/web/tutorial.css
gitslave-2.0.2/web/tutorial-basic.html
gitslave-2.0.2/prep_gitscheck
gitslave-2.0.2/gits
gitslave-2.0.2/Makefile
gitslave-2.0.2/ReleaseNotes
gitslave-2.0.2/README
gitslave-2.0.2/contrib/
gitslave-2.0.2/contrib/gitslave.spec.in
gitslave-2.0.2/contrib/Makefile
gitslave-2.0.2/contrib/gitslave.spec
gitslave-2.0.2/contrib/.gitignore
gitslave-2.0.2/contrib/gitin
gitslave-2.0.2/contrib/gits-checkup
gitslave-2.0.2/.gitignore
gitslave-2.0.2/BugsTodo
gitslave-2.0.2/LICENSE.README
gitslave-2.0.2/LICENSE.TXT
+cd gitslave-2.0.2
+make
pod2man < gits > gits.1
IO::File=IO(0x2363598) around line 1: No name given for document
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 68.
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'gits.1' failed
make: *** [gits.1] Error 255
```

The [install script](https://github.com/vladbailescu/sightly-slaves/blob/master/install-gitslave.sh) is:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex
wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/gitslave/files/gitslave-2.0.2.tar.gz
tar -xzvf gitslave-2.0.2.tar.gz
cd gitslave-2.0.2 && make && sudo make install
```

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I've just tried your script on 19.10 and no errors received. Only two warnings: `Warning: Missing optional Term::ProgressBar.
Warning: Missing optional Parallel::Iterator package.
Consider: make install -C contrib`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem here is that the application is old (from 2012).

You have to provide the name for the man-page which is generated by [`pod2man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pod2man.1.html) (see `--name` option).

```
cd gitslave-2.0.2/
sed 's/pod2man/pod2man --name gits/' -i Makefile
sed 's/pod2man/pod2man --name gits-checkup/' -i contrib/Makefile
```

and then continue the installation as was planned:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thank you very much!